# Count the number of cows after N number of years

Tags: java, recursion

A cow has a calf every year. A calf becomes a cow in 2 years, starting with one cow we have to count how many animals are there in N years.
Suppose no cow ever dies...

eg at N=5:

1st cow gave 2 calves(1 at the age of 2 another at the age of 3, next at 4, next at 5)
total= 4 calves
now the first cow is also already 3 year old so (she gave birth to 1 calf at the age of 2 another at the age of 3)
total = 2 calves.
the second cow must also be 2 year old so she just gave birth to another calf
total = 1 calf.

sum = 1+4+2+1

The reccursion goes on as the year increases

I  recently got this question at an exam.
I tried using recursion, I'm just a beginner and I'm not getting it right.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
    int n= sc.nextInt();
    sc.close();
    fun(n);
}
public static void fun(int age) {
    int arr[] = new int[age-1];
    int temp=0, sum=1;
    for(int i=age-2; i>=0; i--){
        arr[temp++]=i;
    }
    sum+=arr.length;
    for(int j=0; j<age-1; j++) {
        if(arr[j]>=2) {
            fun(j);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: I have found a logic for this but don't know how to write a program as I am not into java. I don't know how to help you. Maybe I could write an algo if you say so

Comment: Another dimension of your question: If a cow has 2 calves: Will those calves eventually be two cows? Or a cow and a bull? And you're probably also not asking about the animals mating with their siblings... You mentioned it was an exam - not which kind of exam. In a job interview - even for a technical/software job- I'd ask for clarification. In biology there's different stuff asked for.

Comment: @AmanjotKaur Sir that will be very appreciable I'll try and imply it from my side.

Comment: @OlafKock 
Sir it doesn't make sense but I think that's how it is. It's always a cow never a bull.

Comment: @TrishaSingh You can also try Lino answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there are more efficient implementations for this problem, but the following is in my point of view easy to explain and understand:

```
public class CowCalculator {
    public static int numberOfCows(int maxAge) {
        int count = 1; // the "root" cow

        for (int year = 2; year <= maxAge; year++) {
            // after the second year, the "root" cow gives birth to one calve every year
            // every calve is a root cow by itself, but with less maximum age
            count += numberOfCows(maxAge - year);
        }

        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(CowCalculator.numberOfCows(5));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your can model the state of your herd with (N0, N1, N) where:

- N0 is the number of calves of less that 1 year,
- N1 is the number of
  calves of at least 1 year, but less than 2 year,
- N is the number of cows (at least 2 years)

At year n+1, you would have:

- N0' = N
- N1' = N0
- N' = N + N1

Then you can write a class Herd:

```
public class Herd {
    private int n0;
    private int n1;
    private int n;

    public Herd(int n0, int n1, int n) {
        set(n0, n1, n);
    }

    private void set(int n0, int n1, int n) {
        this.n0 = n0;
        this.n1 = n1;
        this.n = n;
    }

    public int numberOfCows() {
        return n;
    }

    public int numberOfCalves() {
        return n0 + n1;
    }

    public int numberOfAnimals() {
        return n + n0 + n1;
    }

    public void nextYear() {
        set(n, n0, n+n1);
    }
}
```

If you start with one cow, you can instanciate your `Herd` as follows:

```
Herd herd = new Herd(0,0,1);
```

Then you can print the state of your herd each year:

```
for (int y = 0; y <= 5; ++y) {
    System.out.println("year " + y
            + ": cows: " + herd.numberOfCows()
            + ", calves: " + herd.numberOfCalves());
    herd.nextYear();
}
```

I get the following results:

```
year 0: cows: 1, calves: 0
year 1: cows: 1, calves: 1
year 2: cows: 1, calves: 2
year 3: cows: 2, calves: 2
year 4: cows: 3, calves: 3
year 5: cows: 4, calves: 5
```

So after five years, I have 4 cows and 5 calves, that's a total of 9 animals.

Am I right?

UPDATE:

If you want to compute it recursively, it's very simple: define the (recursive) method:

```
private static void fun(int y, int n0, int n1, int n) {
    if (y == 0) {
        System.out.println("cows: " + n + ", calves: " + (n0+n1));
    } else {
        fun(y-1, n, n0, n+n1);
    }
}
```

Then invoke it (again, for 5 years, starting with 1 cow):

```
    fun(5, 0, 0, 1);
```

Output:

```
cows: 4, calves: 5
```

Same result as before

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. It's not recursive (was that a strict requirement?) but it gets the answer right:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Bovines {

    private static final class Bovine {

        private final int birthYear;

        public Bovine(final int birthYear) {
            this.birthYear = birthYear;
        }

        public boolean isCow(final int year) {
            return (year - this.birthYear) >= 2;
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        final List<Bovine> bovineList = new ArrayList<>();
        /**/               bovineList.add(new Bovine(0));  // (initial Calf)

        for (int year=0; year <= 5; year++) {
            /*
             * Iterate over a copy of the List to avoid any parallel-update issues...
             */
            for (final Bovine bovine : new ArrayList<>(bovineList)) {
                if (bovine.isCow(year)) {
                    bovineList.add(new Bovine(year));  // (Cow has Calf)
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Year.: " + year + " Total: " + bovineList.size());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answer helps. We specifically required to handle calves = 0 case.

```
private static int numCows(int years, int cows, int calves) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= years; i++) {
        if(calves==0) {
            calves = cows;
        } else {
            int start_cows = cows;
            cows = calves;
            calves = start_cows + cows;
        }
    }
    return cows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a variation of "getting the Nth fibonacci number."

The only difference is as follows:

- the number of cows in the first year is 1.
- the number of cows in the second year is 2.

Here is a working solution in Java:

```java
public class Solution {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int years = sc.nextInt();
    if (years == 1) {
      System.out.println(1);
    } else if (years == 2) {
      System.out.println(2);
    } else {
      System.out.println(countCowsRecursive(++years));
    }
  }
  private static int countCowsRecursive(int years) {
   if (years < 3) {
     return 1;
   }
   return (countCowsRecursive(years - 1) + countCowsRecursive(years - 2));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fibonacci series

```
function countCows(n) {
  if (n < 2) return 1;
  return countCows(n - 1) + countCows(n - 2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As already mentioned, this problem is similar to the fibonacci series. Though you're not limited to start with a single cow with zero calves. So I've written this more general method:

```java
private static int numCows(int years, int cows, int calves) {
    for (; 0 < years--; cows += calves, calves = cows - calves);
    return cows;
}
```

Or in a more explanatory way:

```java
private static int numCows(int years, int cows, int calves) {
    for (int i = 0; i < years; i++) {
        int t = cows;
        cows += calves;
        calves = t;
    }
    return cows;
}
```

Which may be called like this (assuming you want the cows in 5 years with a single starting cow and no calves):

```java
int cows = numCows(5, 1, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

In C/C++ will be like the following:

```
int main()
{
    // For Example after 6 years
    printf("Number of Cows after 6 years: %d\n", getCowsCount(6));
    return 0;
}

int getNumOfCows(int year){
   if(year < 0) return 0;
   if(year >= 0 && year <= 2) return 1;
   if(year > 2) return year - 1;
}

int getCowsCount(int year){
   int sum = 0;
   if (year < 0) return 0;
   for(int y=0; y<=year; y++){
       sum += getNumOfCows(y);
   }
   return sum;
}
```